# How do I bind the visibility property of a DataGridTextColumn using code in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am trying to bind the visibility property of a DataGridTextColumn in WPF using code.  Specifically, I need to bind it to the datacontext of a framework element.

```
 <FrameworkElement x:Name="DataContextControl"/>
```

In Xaml, I would do :

```
<DataGridTextColumn Visibility="{Binding DataContext, Source = {x:Reference DataContextControl}}">
```

I am building the columns dynamically so that's not an option here.  How do I do the same binding programmatically since DataGridTextColumn doesn't have a setbinding command?

I have tried using SetValue to no avail.

Comment: Anything useful here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916454/how-can-i-set-the-binding-of-a-datagridtextcolumn-in-code

Comment: No, that refers to the binding property on the column, but I need to be able to bind to the visibility property.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via `BindingOperations`:

```
var column = new DataGridTextColumn();
BindingOperations.SetBinding(
    column,
    DataGridColumn.VisibilityProperty,
    new Binding(...));
```